# Пожалуйста, помогите расставить пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение

> Я тут немного влюбилась, и вспомнилось кое-что из   Олейникова. Автор "Мухи" — милейшая девушка Тамила, познакомила меня с "цветом кетонала".

Comment: Строго говоря, расставляют не пунктуацию, а знаки препинания. Пунктуациа — это и есть расстановка знаков препинания или раздел языкознания, изучающий знаки препинания и правила их употребления.

Answer (score 3):

Я тут немного влюбилась, и вспомнилось кое-что из Олейникова.  *Автор "Мухи" — милейшая девушка Тамила — познакомила меня с "цветом кетонала".*

Обособленное приложение в середине предложения (при отсутствии запятых в месте вставки) выделяется запятыми или тире. В данном случае лучше использовать тире, так как это дополнительная информация.